# Can I force lmfit Gaussian models to all have positive amplitudes?

Tags: python, scipy, gaussian, lmfit

I'm fitting gaussian curves to some data, and while the "fit" is extremely impressive, it sometimes uses negative amplitudes to achieve it. The code below results in a plot of the data, fit, and constituent gaussian curves. You'll see one overwhelming gaussian curve with an amplitude of 577 and another with an amplitude of -570 which contribute to the fit curve.

I'd prefer a fit that would sacrifice a bit of "precision" for forcing all the amplitudes positive. Are there any ways to force the parameters of the models to keep amplitudes positive?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import signal
import math
from lmfit import models

perc = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000019, 0.000294, 0.001946, 0.007003, 0.017276, 0.033345, 0.055974, 0.086622, 0.126049, 0.173105, 0.226678, 0.286038, 0.351443, 0.42241, 0.498498, 0.578561, 0.661742, 0.746826, 0.83285, 0.919105, 1.00482, 1.08944, 1.17218, 1.25306, 1.33216, 1.40968, 1.48517, 1.55839, 1.62919, 1.69746, 1.7625, 1.82327, 1.87912, 1.93017, 1.97694, 2.01944, 2.05721, 2.08996, 2.11797, 2.14111, 2.15795, 2.16612, 2.16457, 2.15517, 2.14131, 2.125, 2.10617, 2.08647, 2.07406, 2.08323, 2.12419, 2.19053, 2.25702, 2.29272, 2.28612, 2.25781, 2.24839, 2.29069, 2.38262, 2.48227, 2.52351, 2.44913, 2.24458, 1.94567, 1.61752, 1.32053, 1.08224, 0.895022, 0.730309, 0.559126, 0.375057, 0.205875, 0.099411, 0.06067, 0.063161, 0.079791, 0.089018, 0.073056, 0.041268, 0.014748, 0.002668, 0.000197, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
gsize = [0.04, 0.04391, 0.048203, 0.052916, 0.058089, 0.063768, 0.070002, 0.076845, 0.084358, 0.092605, 0.101658, 0.111597, 0.122507, 0.134483, 0.147631, 0.162064, 0.177907, 0.1953, 0.214393, 0.235353, 0.258361, 0.283619, 0.311346, 0.341784, 0.375198, 0.411878, 0.452145, 0.496347, 0.544872, 0.59814, 0.656615, 0.720807, 0.791275, 0.868632, 0.953552, 1.04677, 1.14911, 1.26145, 1.38477, 1.52015, 1.66876, 1.8319, 2.011, 2.2076, 2.42342, 2.66033, 2.92042, 3.20592, 3.51934, 3.8634, 4.2411, 4.65572, 5.11087, 5.61052, 6.15902, 6.76114, 7.42212, 8.14773, 8.94427, 9.81869, 10.7786, 11.8323, 12.9891, 14.2589, 15.6529, 17.1832, 18.863, 20.7071, 22.7315, 24.9538, 27.3934, 30.0714, 33.0113, 36.2385, 39.7813, 43.6704, 47.9397, 52.6264, 57.7713, 63.4192, 69.6192, 76.4253, 83.8969, 92.0988, 101.103, 110.987, 121.837, 133.748, 146.824, 161.177, 176.935, 194.232, 213.221, 234.066, 256.948, 282.068, 309.644, 339.916, 373.147, 409.626, 449.672, 493.633, 541.892, 594.869, 653.025, 716.866, 786.949, 863.883, 948.338, 1041.05, 1142.83, 1254.55, 1377.2, 1511.84, 1659.64, 1821.89]

xinit = gsize
xlog = [math.log(xval) for xval in xinit]
x = np.array(xlog)
y = np.array(perc)

peaks = signal.find_peaks_cwt(y, (2.5, 25))             
xstep = x.ptp() / len(x)

model, params = None, None

for i, peak_index in enumerate(peaks):
    this_model = models.GaussianModel(prefix=f'p{1+i:d}_')
    this_params = this_model.make_params(amplitude=y[peak_index], center=x[peak_index], sigma=2*xstep)
    if model is None:
        model = this_model
        params = this_params
    else:
        model += this_model
        params.update(this_params)

result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

params_list = ['p1_', 'p2_', 'p3_', 'p4_', 'p5_', 'p6_']
plt.plot(figsize=(60, 50))
plt.ylim(-4.0, 4.0)
for param in params_list:
   try:
                
       center = result.params[param + 'center'].value
       sigma = result.params[param + 'sigma'].value
       mean = center
       standard_deviation = sigma
       amplitude = result.params[param + 'amplitude'].value
       x_values = np.arange(-2, 10, 0.1)
       y_values = scipy.stats.norm(mean, standard_deviation)
       plt.plot(x_values, (amplitude*y_values.pdf(x_values)))

   except KeyError:
       continue

plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have too many degrees of freedom and it will overfit.

If you fit a model with only three gaussians

```py
for i, peak_index in enumerate(peaks[:3]):
    this_model = models.GaussianModel(prefix=f'p{1+i:d}_')
    this_params = this_model.make_params(amplitude=y[peak_index], center=x[peak_index], sigma=2*xstep)
    if model is None:
        model = this_model
        params = this_params
    else:
        model += this_model
        params.update(this_params)
```

It will not use negative amplitudes

[image: 3 gaussians]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set each 'amplitude' parameter to be positive.  Something like:

```
for i, peak_index in enumerate(peaks):
    this_model = models.GaussianModel(prefix=f'p{1+i:d}_')
    this_params = this_model.make_params(amplitude=y[peak_index],
                                         center=x[peak_index], 
                                         sigma=2*xstep)
    this_params[f'p{1+i:d}_amplitude'].min = 0.  # <--- set min value here!

    if model is None:
        model = this_model
        params = this_params
    else:
        model += this_model
        params.update(this_params)
```

ought to do it.